# I can't get Nuget push command to work on Visual Studio Online using latest Nuget tasks

Tags: nuget, .net-core, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio Online. My team has recently switched to Asp.Net core 1.1 for our web development. Before we had a working nuget publishing process, but that doesn't work anymore because the old nuget tasks are deprecated.

I'm already aware that there should be Nuget package task before the push task, but that task has a known bug for .Net core. Instead I set up my project in VS so that the build task generates my .nupkg file.

Here is my setup from vs-online:

[My setup for Nuget push task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvs8E.png)

The result looks like this:

[The result when running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESYJR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem myself.

I changed the path to:

```
**/*.nupkg;-:**/packages/**/*.nupkg;-:**/*.symbols.nupkg
```